# MPMoviePlayerController not setting the bounds for background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController for playing the media . I want to set the image at the background of the player.The image is set accordingly but when i set the bounds for the image then the image is not set according to bounds . I have tried following code:

```
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[operationControl getCoverImage:stringId]];
    imageView.bounds=CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 200);
    [moviePlayer.backgroundView addSubview:imageView];
    [moviePlayer.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];   
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: what do you mean set according to the bounds?  also, the frame property is how you position a view relative to it's parent.